# height: 100% not working when parent div only has max-height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can't wrap my head around it! I try to make parent div to take no more than 80% height of the window with `max-height`, and child div to take all parent height minus something.

But `height` property in percents of the parent doesn't work for the child at all, unless I give parent `height` property.

Why is that?

Here is my simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbatcer/m2ohnsf5/
Why does inner div not respect parent height and go out of container?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/70x300">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {  
  background: blue; 
  padding: 10px; 
  max-height: 100px; 
}

.inner { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: An element with its height set using percent, will also need its parent to have a height and so on, all the way to the html/body, or til an element has a height other than using percent, and `max-height` has nothing to do with that. Also, if you set the height using percent on the parent as well, you also need to set a height  to the html/body, or else it won't work. Why it is like this? ... The height on html, body and elements default to auto, and when using percent on an element, it query its parent for its height, which will return auto, hence it will end up with 0.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
.container {  
  background: blue; 
  padding: 10px; 
  max-height: 100px; 
  display: flex;

}

.inner { 
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f9sfczya/1/

Here I added display: flex; in your parent div and removed height: 100%;
 from child div.

Unfortunately display: flex; is unsupported by IE9 and older.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: This doesn't resize the image. It only clips (overflow: hidden) the part of the image that goes beyond the flex parent max height. https://jsfiddle.net/ncu4q3xa/

Answer (score 2):

If you set child's `max-height` with a percentage, it will set the child's `height` according to the parent's real `height` instead of the `max-height`. 
So you will need to set a height to your `.container` and set a `max-height: 100%` to your image since your image has lager height than width.

```
.container {  
  background: blue; 
  padding: 10px; 
  height: 100px; 
}

.inner { 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

---

A better way to solve this problem is to use `flex-box`.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;  
  background: blue; 
  padding: 10px; 
  max-height: 80vh; 
}

.inner { 
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:80vh;` to `.container` and it will work.

Comment: The second sentence in my question is: "I try to make parent div to take no more than 80% height of the window".

Answer (score -1):

You should change your CSS like this-

```
.container {  
  background: blue; 
  padding: 10px; 
}

.inner { 
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner img { 
  max-height: 100px;
}
```